Boy grows up to be a warrior, searches for his mother's killer
I'm trying to remember a title of a movie I watched some years ago. The movie is set in the times where people still fought with swords. In the begining of the movie there was a scene where a village was attacked by a group of soldiers or bandits. And a young boy's mother was killed by a man with a black tattoo on his hand. The boy watched all this. Later the boy grew up as a warrior and was trying to avenge his mother by looking for that man with a black dragon or wolf tattoo on his hand.
Please help, I really loved that movie and I want to watch it again.

Really? 'Cause I have a different movie in mind... @mario, by 'some years ago' do you mean it's recent? Do you know the country\language?

It sure sounds like Conan, Thulsa Doom had the whole double headed snake thing going on...

But I don't think he had a tattoo like the OP describes, and there is one in this movie. Waiting for more details, but maybe I should just put it up.

OK. I retract my comment that it can only be Conan. It just sounded way too obvious.

Well, it borrows liberally from Conan (and LOTR)

@Walt yes, no tattoo, that's why I left it as "that whole double headed snake thing"...But I'm sure somebody's got that tattoo by now.

"Hello, My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father; prepare to die."

If you mean it's recent, it could be the Russian sword-and-sorcery, Conan-esque epic Wolfhound (2006). From an online review:

Opening segment, milked for maximum sentimental effect, shows a young boy
  [...] seeing his dad, mom (eight months pregnant, no less) and whole tribe
  slaughtered by a warlord called Ogre (Aleksandr Domogarov), his minions and
  an evil, masked druid with a wolf tattoo on his hand.
Years later, the traumatized tot emerges as grown man named Volkodav
  (the name literally means “wolfhound,” played by local TV star Aleksandr Bukharov), who, after escaping the slave mines, has picked up ace swordsmanship skills, a mean facial scar, a pet bat (CGI-generated) and a quest for revenge.

Here's the trailer (with subtitles):




Nice pull, Walt!

Conan-esque? Sounds more like a Conan-rip-off, to me, lol. I'm sure this made Robert E. Howard roll over in his grave. +1 on the find, no less :D
